# Old short story where the future emperor of the galaxy is taken for a tour around Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This short story is about a future emperor of the galaxy who is brought to Earth for what he thinks is a tour. A guide takes him around Earth on horseback and keeps saying “your life is in my hands”. The prince thinks the guide is  security and he is there on a vacation.  In reality the prince is being evaluated. In the end he turns out to be a coward and the guide has to kill him.

Comment: This sounds a previous question in the last few years.

Comment: Possibly the same as [Fantasy Short Story that appeared in an anthology about 1968-1971](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54996/fantasy-short-story-that-appeared-in-an-anthology-about-1968-1971) and also [Looking for short story from Asimov's Foundation universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167257/looking-for-short-story-from-asimovs-foundation-universe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fantasy Short Story that appeared in an anthology about 1968-1971](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54996/fantasy-short-story-that-appeared-in-an-anthology-about-1968-1971)

Comment: Not a dupe because not yet accepted.

Answer (score 33):

Gordon R. Dickson *Call Him Lord*. The visit to Earth is a kind of "manhood test" to reveal the Prince's suitability (or not) to be the next Emperor.

When the  escort meets the Emperor, the latter demands to know how his son failed the test. After going over a few lesser problems, the escort gets to the heart of the matter, saying "Lord. He was a coward," and the Emperor of a hundred worlds recoils in shame.

This first appeared in the May 1966 *Analog*. There is [a Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_Him_Lord).

Comment: If accepted (I agree it's correct) then a duplicate of this old question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54996/fantasy-short-story-that-appeared-in-an-anthology-about-1968-1971

Comment: @OrganicMarble, just because the answer is the same, it doesn't mean the Question is the same. To me, the Questions differ significantly in description of events.

Comment: Here's the site policy: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance Have a nice day.